# How to redirect to a page after submitting the form in php

Tags: php, forms, form-submit

I made a form in php and after submitting the form, I wanna redirect to aboutus page, the form is working fine and Im getting proper mail but I just need redirection.

here is my code

`<?php if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {     $to = "myemailhere@mail.com";     $from = $_POST['email'];     $name = $_POST['name'];     $phone = $_POST['phone'];     $email = $_POST['email'];     $subject = $_POST['subject'];     $subject = "Form submission";     $message = "Query Request from:" . "\n\n" . "Name : " . $_POST['name'] . "\n\n" . "Email : " . $_POST['email'] . "\n\n" . "Number : " . $_POST['phone'] . "\n\n" . "Subject : " . $_POST['subject'] . "\n\n" . "Message : " . $_POST['message'];     $headers = "From:" . $from;     $headers2 = "From:" . $to;     mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);     mail($from, $subject2, $message2, $headers2);     echo '<script type="text/javascript">';     echo ' alert("Mail Sent. Thank you, we will contact you shortly.")'; //not showing an alert box. redirect('/index.php'); echo '</script>'; }      ?>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a redirect in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-do-i-make-a-redirect-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

The do a redirection in php, you need to use the function [`header('Location: '.$newURL.php);`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

Have a good day.